# Nested Routes in Rails 3.2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am trying to create nested routes for a project that has many boards.

First I am creating a link to a new board:

```
<%= link_to 'New Board', new_project_board_path(@project) %>
```

In routes.rb I just nested the restful routes:

```
resources :projects do
  resources :boards
end
```

And in the boards controller I adapted the new and create action as follows:

```
    def new
        @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
        @board = @project.boards.new

        respond_to do |format|
          format.html # new.html.erb
          format.json { render json: @board }
        end
  end



 def create
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @board = @project.boards.new(params[:board])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @board.save
        format.html { redirect_to @board, notice: 'Board was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @board, status: :created, location: @board }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @board.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

At least I also changed the _form.html.erb into:

```
<%= form_for([@project, @board]) do |f| %>
```

etc.

My problem starts when I click the button create board (so the new action is executed) it says no route matches. I guess it has to do with the create action because it doesn't get the id of the project anymore? I really don't know what else to change and where.

Comment: Can you paste the actual error?

Comment: No route matches [GET] "/boards/39"

Comment: the url doesnt fit after clicking creating board.. before that it has the right one I guess: http://localhost:3000/projects/5/boards/new

Comment: Based on the error, it sounds like @dimuch may have the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems your error is here

```
format.html { redirect_to @board, notice: 'Board was successfully created.' }
```

You don't have non-nested :boards resources, do you? Try to change this line to

```
format.html { redirect_to [@project, @board], notice: 'Board was successfully created.' }
```